# Make most recently entered text in UITextField visible when not editing

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

With a Swift UITextField the default behavior when not editing is to ellipse the most recently entered text if the text is too long to fit in the space allowed for the text field. As shown in this image:
[image: UITextField when not editing]

When you begin to edit the text field, the text shifts left to make the most recently entered text visible. As shown in this image:
[image: UITextField when editing]

How can I achieve this effect when I am not editing the text field? I would like the most recently viewed text to always be visible no matter whether or not the user is currently editing the text field. If the text is too long for the space provided for the text field, it should not display the oldest text.

Answer (score 0):

This could be easily achieved using `UITextView` if that suits other requirements:

```
let textView = UITextView()
textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 1
textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingHead
```